# RStudio Connect : Invalid Redirect on Login (ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT)

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, rstudio

I have set up RStudio Connect to run on port 444 on an AWS EC2 instance. When I hit my rstudio connect adress, https://myaddress.com:444 I get redirected to the RStudio Connect frontpage. Thats great!

I can also press the "sign up" bottom and get redirected without any problems. Here I can create my user as normal.

However when I try to press login, I get "ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT". It was not a problem when I was running on port 443 (standard https). Anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Do you have access to RStudio's support?

Comment: I assume so yes. You think I should open a ticket with them?

Comment: It would be my first step.

Comment: okay thanks. I just hoped it was a simple issue - but i guess its more complicated than that

Comment: I don't know what the issue is, but that's what they're there for. If they say this is outside the scope of support, I would ask the question at community.rstudio.com to see if others who have RS Connect have an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to run Rstudio connect and server on the SAME EC2 instance. Server on port 443 and Connect on port 444. I was not able for some reason to run Connect on port 444 as described above.

A workaround was simply to run Rstudio Server on port 444 and connect on port 443 - then there was no problems.